# How do I get rid of a random semi-circle on floor that shows up after scene is rendered??

Tags: rendering

There is an annoying shadow that is showing up in the middle of the floor after I render the scene! I have no idea where it is coming from. I am new at this, and just trying to change the materials on the floor. See image (bottom render) att[image]

Comment: could you upload your blendfile?

Comment: Is "that shadow" affecting only the floor material? Could you post its material node?

Comment: It would really help if you could upload your .blend file to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and post the link in the question.

Comment: thank you so much for offering to help! somehow the shadow disappeared. I'm sure it will come back again, at which I will have to re-post and will add the link next time.  thanks again!

Comment: @user16320 Okay :) In that case I've closed this question. BTW, my guess is that this might be cycles's form of z-fighting, where two floor meshes are in the same place.